# How did Nick Fury lose his left eye?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In ***Captain America: The Winter Soldier***, Nick Fury and Captain America have the following conversation.

> **Steve Rogers**: Soldiers trust each other, that's what makes it an army. Not a bunch of guys running around and shooting guns.
>
> **Nick Fury**: The last time I trusted someone, I lost an eye.

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, is it ever explained how Nick Fury lost his eye?

Comment: Apparently it might be answered in the upcoming movie Captain Marvel : https://www.inverse.com/article/35090-captain-marvel-nick-fury-samuel-l-jackson-two-eyes-eyepatch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now that Captain Marvel is out, we finally know how Fury lost his left eye in the MCU.

He was playing with and petting Goose, the "cat" they found in the research facility, and Goose scratched his eye. The scars around his eye are also from Goose, who is actually a Flerken, an alien race.

Comment: Seeing how the question is about the entire MCU, we can safely assume people are looking for answers from all the films. I'd thus remove the spoiler block in favour of the information and answering the question properly.

Answer (score 10):

No. It is not explained in the Marvel Cinematic Universe ever except the conversation you already mentioned. This may or may not be explained in future films, but it is pure speculation for now.

However, it is explained in the comic world.

In Earth-616, Nick Fury fought in World War II as part of the Howling Commandos. A grenade by Nazi soldier was thrown at him. Though he caught it, but delayed throwing it back. The shrapnel he was hit with was what caused the damage that would slowly deteriorate the vision in his left eye, eventually leaving him almost completely blind in that eye.

[image]

> In the Ultimate Marvel Universe, **his eye was injured due to a bombing he was caught in alongside James Howlett** — a.k.a. Wolverine/Logan — during the Gulf War, but unlike his Earth-616 counterpart, he completely lost the eyeball and was left with bad scarring around the now empty socket.

[Source and Image Courtesy](https://moviepilot.com/p/how-did-nick-fury-loose-his-eye/3921025)

Comment: in comics nick fury is caucasian right? not african american? (pardon if Im not politically correct on those terms)

Comment: Yes. Nick Fury is not African American in comics.

Comment: @AJ well he is in Ultimate Marvel.

Comment: @AJ, Fun fact: The Ultimate Marvel Nick Fury (or at least, the action figure of him) was based on Sam L Jackson (with his permission). When it came to casting someone for the films, it was then natural that they went with SLJ.